# How to move the input layout go up when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, keyboard

I'm sorry if any similar question has been resolved in other topics. I have a screen with the root is a frame layout.

- The layout in back contains a lot of content
- The layout in front contains an edit text to allow user enter some text. Normally, it put at the bottom of the screen.

What I expected is when the keyboard appears, the layout contains content is keep unchanged while the layout contains edit text move up to the keyboard.

Please check the images below

[image]

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to edit the activity tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
   <!-- Configures the keyboard to be hidden right away and for UI to keep content as is when shown -->
   <activity
    android:name="com.example.myactivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

more info can be found [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard).

Comment: Sorry, I want to move a view group with the edittext only. Not the whole screen.

Comment: try to put your content is a ScrollView and change `adjustPan` to `adjustResize`